# onclicklistener for a blank screen android studio

Tags: onclicklistener

How to handle a click on Intent's window? I know how to process a click on a button or edit box, but I could not find a way to handle a click, for example, made on the space free of any button or edit text. In other words, how to handle a click on a blank screen? Thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set an ID for the layout on set a listener on it

```
 View fab = findViewById(R.id.id);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Where id is the id of the layout